# create groupbox in new panel dynamically

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to create groupbox in my new panel dynamically. How i do this in vb.net? thank you.......................

```
Dim Groups As New Dictionary(Of String, GroupBox)
Dim Panels As New Dictionary(Of String, Panel)
Dim jmlpnl As Integer = 1
Dim jmlgrp As Integer = 10

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim pnl As New Panel
    For i As Integer = 1 To jmlpnl
        Me.Controls.Add(pnl)
        pnl.Width = 883
        pnl.Height = 744
        pnl.Top = 5
        pnl.Left = 439
        pnl.BackColor = Color.White
        Panels.Add("Panel" & i, pnl)
        pnl.Tag = "Panel" & i
        For j As Integer = 1 To jmlgrp
           'create groupbox in my new panel
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Since you are doing it in Form Load why not just put them on the form via the designer?

Comment: I want to make user can add panel & groupbox whenever he wants

Comment: If you have an unknown amount of controls you'll be displaying, you might consider putting them in a `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a not very difficult task. You just have to create the new groupboxes and add them to the Panel. The only thing you must have in mind is the distribution, this code just puts them one right to the other, if you want something different you'll need to play with the `top` and `left` variables:

```
Dim top As Integer = 0
Dim left As Integer = 0
For j As Integer = 1 To jmlgrp
    'create groupbox in my new panel
    Dim grp As New GroupBox
    grp.Width = 50
    grp.Height = 50
    grp.Top = top
    grp.Left = left

    pnl.Controls.Add(grp)
    left += 60
Next
```